# Display php code when php script is executed

Tags: php

How to display this php code when php script is executed.
I only want to display these syntax not the result of the syntax.

This is for a making tutorial web site.

```
//sample code
$con = mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error ());
$db = mysql_select_db ("arraydb") or die(mysql_error ());
$i=0;

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE i_id=130';
$query = mysql_query($sql);

foreach($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) as $key => $value)
{
    echo '<pre>['.$key.' - '.$value.']</pre>';  
}
echo '<hr/>%%<br><br><br>';
```

p.s i tried to type code without php tags then 

1.html tags are not display

2.text indenting format is not visible in result

Comment: Don't put it in a PHP block then...

Comment: P.S.  Don't create another tutorial using mysql_ functions.  There are already too many bad ones out there.

Comment: i want to display html tags also

Comment: What you mean with "when php script executed" ? The same code or another php script ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your code is in "sample.php" you could add the following line at the begining of your file or somewhere before the first "echo":

```
highlight_file('sample.php');
```

Note that you will see this line as well in the code sample.

You can try this http://micmap.org/php-by-example/en/function/highlight_string to get an idea of what it produces.

Did you try something like this ?

```
<?php
highlight_file(__FILE__);
echo '<br>';

// begin sample code
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
echo $a + $b;
// end sample code, result displayed below
```

Comment: I think highlight function don't need `echo` unless you add second parameter true to return its value to a variable then echo the variable

Comment: works if code is in separate file...
how to do it when code is not in separate file

Comment: @Susantha7 use `highlight_string()` ... did you even look into the docs once??

Comment: tried it as shows below. but show error messages $Strt = <<<a //code a; highlight_string($Strt); –

Comment: want to display

//code

//result

//code

//result

Answer (score 0):

use enclosed tags 
   < pre >
   < /pre >

Comment: tried it as shows below.
but show error messages


$Strt = <<<a
      //code
a;

highlight_string($Strt);